# Convert TensorFlow model with boolean input placeholder to TensorFlow Lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a ResNet model which I trained with Ubuntu 16.04 and TensorFlow v1.10.0. I want to convert this model for use in TensorFlow Lite.

The model has two input placeholders. First, the image (1 x 512 x 512 x 3) and then a boolean placeholder which is defined as

```
is_training = tf.placeholder_with_default(False, shape=(), name="is_training")
```

I convert the model to a standalone GraphDef file as follows:

```
bazel run -c opt tensorflow/python/tools:freeze_graph -- --input_graph=/home/user/model/graph.pbtxt --input_checkpoint=/home/user/model/model-checkpoint --output_graph=/home/user/model/frozen.pb --output_node_names=output
```

which works.

In a second step, I want to convert the standalone GraphDef file to the TFLite format:

```
bazel run -c opt //tensorflow/contrib/lite/python:tflite_convert -- --output_file=/home/user/model/model.lite --graph_def_file=/home/user/model/frozen_model.pb --input_arrays=model_input/input --output_arrays=output --input_shape=1,512,512,3
```

which fails with the following error message:

```
RuntimeError: TOCO failed see console for info.
b'2018-08-14 10:10:00.486547: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
2018-08-14 10:10:00.680867: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1096] Converting unsupported operation: Iterator
2018-08-14 10:10:00.680949: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1096] Converting unsupported operation: IteratorGetNext
2018-08-14 10:10:00.804511: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before Removing unused ops: 1662 operators, 2722 arrays (0 quantized)
2018-08-14 10:10:00.860103: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] After Removing unused ops pass 1: 1551 operators, 2558 arrays (0 quantized)
2018-08-14 10:10:00.933723: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before general graph transformations: 1551 operators, 2558 arrays (0 quantized)
2018-08-14 10:10:00.934610: F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/resolve_tensorflow_switch.cc:95] Check failed: other_op->type == OperatorType::kMerge 
Aborted (core dumped)
'
None
```

I can work around this issue by replacing the above placeholder variable with

```
is_training = False
```

as I already described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18731#issuecomment-402653151)

I'd like to avoid this workaround and convert my models directly. Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: Please do not remove some lines and show the **entire** log. I reverted back your edits and changed `\n` to new lines.

Comment: makes sense. thanks @Patwie

Comment: There is a seemingly related bug [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20878). The conclusion being "The error message has been updated to give a little more context on the issue. Unfortunately, supporting arbitrary switch statements won't be supported in the near future. The best next step is to figure out how to prune that from the graph."